# error in get connection method

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a dynamic jtree in netbeans using Oracle XE.

I have made a `connection()` method in `packageA` and use the `connection()` method in `pacakge B`.

Earlier it was not giving the error but now the connection method work perfectly fine some times & and some times it show the error message `error java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=169869568)(ERR=12516)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12516)(EMFI=4))))`.

My code is following for `getConnection()`

```
public class IntegrationWithDbClass {

public Connection conn = null;
public Statement stmt = null;
public ResultSet rs = null;
public String query = "";

        public void getConnection() {

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
 String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "Hr", "Hr");
System.out.println("Connection Established");
        if (this.conn != null) {
            this.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error "+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
  }
```

I know that some people said its because of `SID`, but I don't think my error occurs because of `SID`, there is some other problem, need your help thanks.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, and explain why you think your problem is not related to the SID. Note that a connection refused means that on a low level the socket connection could not be established, which would mean that either Oracle is not running on the specified port, or a firewall is blocking your connection.

Comment: 'Connection refused' means exactly one thing. Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. It has nothing to do with 'flaky network connections', firewalls, etc. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @EJP You're right, fixed it. But firewalls can be involved if they are configured to reject instead of drop, and other reason - on Windows - could be that the accept queue is full.